# How to target an element inside an iframe that has no Id or Class attributes?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I can't put any id or class to the iframe I work because of some technical issues, and this iframe sometimes don't show any content inside and I am having a blank space instead. 
I wanted to make the iframe disappear when it loads blank, to protect my page's structure with javascript.

Here is the code I wanted to make it disappear when there are no contents.

```
<div id="myDiv">

 <iframe width="363" height="300"  src="javascript:false">

    <div id="iframeDiv"> 
     ----Contents----
    </div>

  </iframe>

 </div>
```

I tried below script but somehow it doesn't work. Thanks in advance.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 setTimeout(function () {

  var  myTag=document.getElementById('myDiv').getElementsByTagName('iframe');
  var myTagContent = myTag.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
  var myTagDiv = myTagContent.innerDoc.getElementById('iframeDiv');
  if (myTagDiv === null) 
     {
     document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "none";
     }
 }, 500);
 </script>
```

Comment: "somehow it doesn't work" — You need to provide a *clear problem statement*. Do some basic debugging. Look for error messages in the console. Log the values of variables that you are testing to see if they have the values you expect.

Comment: I don't receive any error messages. I tried everything in my capabilities to understand why my code won't work. That is why I used "somehow" word. Sorry for the ambiguity. At first I managed to target and hide the blank area. However even if iframe had content my script code hided it. I suspect my way of handling the issue is wrong. I hope more capable devs can correct my way of approach to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the outer `<div>` before `<iframe>`.

Add `id="ifr"` to `<iframe>` tag.

Then:

`iframeDivElement = window.parent.getElementById('ifr').document.getElementById(iframeDiv');`

**EDIT**:
Alternatively you can use iframe index in your document.

`iframeDivElement = window.parent.frames[0].document.getElementById(iframeDiv');`

Comment: Unfortunately I can't add an id or class to the iframe. That's my main problem here.

Comment: You can enumerate frames using `window.frames`. See EDIT in my answer.

Comment: Thakn you very much. Unfortunately this didn't make the blank iframe disappear. I modified my script with your help like below. Do you see any errors?

    iframeDivElement = 
    window.parent.frames[0].document.getElementById('iframeDiv');
    if (iframeDivElement === null) 
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "none";
    }
    }, 500);

Comment: You should compare like this:
`if (iframeDivElement == undefined) ...`

Comment: Unfortunately nothing happens.

Comment: If you have an empty content of the `<div> (iframeDiv)`, but the `div` tag is still here, - `iframeDivElement` will always be non-null and not `undefined`.